# Newtonsoft failing for large integers: how to use Decimal instead of Int64?

Tags: serialization, json.net

I'm using the Newtonsoft binary to serialize/deserialize a stream into a JSON object:

```
public static JObject LoadFrom(Stream stream)
{
    return JObject.Load(new JsonTextReader(new StreamReader(stream)));
}
```

If the stream contains some large integer like 18446744073709552000, then this call will fail with the error - `JSON integer 18446744073709552000 is too large or small for an Int64`. This is because Newtonsoft is reading it as an integer instead of a decimal. Now I know I can work around this by tweaking the source library and changing the datatypes used in serializing. However, in this situation I only have access to the binary and not the source code - is there an API-level workaround for this?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know if Stream is a double precision value. Did you try casting to a [BigInteger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you on the latest version of Json.Net?  This works just fine for me using [version 5.0.8](http://json.codeplex.com/releases/view/113546):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string json = @"{ test: 18446744073709552000 }";
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json));
        JObject jo = LoadFrom(ms);
        JToken token = jo["test"];
        Console.WriteLine("value type = " + token.Type);
        Console.WriteLine("as string = " + token.ToString());
        decimal d = token.ToObject<decimal>();
        Console.WriteLine("as decimal = " + d);
    }

    public static JObject LoadFrom(Stream stream)
    {
        return JObject.Load(new JsonTextReader(new StreamReader(stream)));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
value type = Integer
as string = 18446744073709552000
as decimal = 18446744073709552000
```

Comment: Thanks, this was indeed the issue. I feel stupid now.